# MySQL Count presence of a value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table called Customers with a CustID column and three other columns called Prod1, Prod2, Prod3.  The Prod columns have a value for each customer of either '0' or '1' denoting if the customer has that particular product or not (1=they have it, 0=they don't) i.e:

```
      CustID   Prod1   Prod2   Prod3
     -------------------------------
      001     1       1        0
      002     0       0        1
      003     1       1        1
      004     1       0        1
```

I want to get a total of how many customers have each product i.e. my output needs to be:

```
      Prod   Count   
     --------------
      Prod1   3  
      Prod2   2     
      Prod3   3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: this is exactly why we should learn normalization before putting it into production

Comment: inquisitive is definitely right.  If you can normalize the database it will save you a lot of headache down the road.  What if your product base grows exponentially?  Are you going to want potentially 100s of fields to specify each product.  A customer is an object with certain characteristics and a Product is an object with a different set of characteristics.  They should be two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "Prod1" AS Prod, Sum(Prod1) As [Count] FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT "Prod2" AS Prod, Sum(Prod2) As [Count] FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT "Prod3" AS Prod, Sum(Prod3) As [Count] FROM Customers
```

Comment: **@user2847583**, did you find an answer to your question?  Or have you solved it on your own?